# Most part or most parts

Tags: grammar

People I'm new here.

I use grammarly and grammarly keeps telling that the following sentence is wrong:

> There is no drinking water in **MOST PART** of the island, so make sure
> you bring loads of it with you.

And rewrites to:

> There is no drinking water in **MOST PARTS** of the island, so make
> sure you bring loads of it with you.

Aren't they equivalent and right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grammarly is (in this case) right.  The two are not the same and only the second is idiomatic.

You are making an observation about the various parts of the island. There are many parts of the island, and so you use a plural noun.

You may be getting confused with the phrase "for the most part".  This phrase means "usually".  The singular "part" here is because this phrase uses old grammar that isn't part of regular English.  Your example does not use this phrase, so you can't use the old grammar.

Comment: So: Usually = SINGULAR : Most part / When we talk about whole things that can be divided = PLURAL : Most parts. RIGHT?

Comment: Use "most part" in the expression "for the most part" (which means "usually").  In other cases use "most parts".

Comment: "For the most part, there is no water on the island." "Most parts of the island have no water." Both are correct, and mean almost the same thing.

Comment: I've been speaking English for nearly seventy years, **most part** of which I'd make a small distinction. "Most part" means "generally" or "the majority". "Most parts" is often used in a geographical sense (as here) or to describe the majority of the "parts" of an object (Most parts of my bicycle are made of metal). I'd say that Grammarly is skating on thin ice with this assertion.

Comment: @Magoo I would say "for the most part of which". This works when describing period of time, not so well for a geographic area. I can't say exactly why, except to observe that some idioms work in certain circumstances and not others. For example, one could say, "Most of the time I find it too hot for my comfort." I would not say, "Most of the island I find it too hot for my comfort." On the other hand, "There is no water on **the greater part** of the island seems perfectly fine to me.